# Windows service started and then stopped

Tags: .net, windows-services

I have created a windows application which runs fine and then i try to run this application as a windows service. After i start the service i got the error like below
[image]

Below are the error log i got from the EventViewer\Application

**Faulting application name: MyApp.Client.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x50fce240
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdaae
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00009617
Faulting process id: 0x1a7c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdf7a1dcc54dc3
Faulting application path: E:\Email Service\Mobile\MyService\Main\Source\Client\Service\Service1\bin\Release\MyApp.Client.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 2ef633e5-6395-11e2-8e41-e4115b2d2915**

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: How are you installing/running this application as a service?

Comment: I need to run this application as a background service

Comment: this is the link i followed to create windows service http://www.instantfundas.com/2008/08/how-to-run-windows-applications-as.html

Comment: I understand - but there are many ways to (try to) run .NET code as a service. Did you create the code in a service project (or in some other way, derive from `ServiceBase`)? Or is it a console application that you're using some kind of "we run your console app as a service" helper? Or TopShelf? etc.

Comment: No.I just create a normal windows Application only

Answer (score 1):

Its a very vague error. I can result from number of things and definitely not a code error.

- Windows patch requires a restart. sfc /scannow on command prompt as admin.
- The kernal.dll should normal exist on the location mentioned on the error else run the regsvr32 KERNELBASE.dll on command prompt as admin.
- Restart your server.
- Make sure correct framework is installed and any reference into  your configs.
- Correct service user if it was supposed to run with specific access or permission.
- Make sure your application configuration is set to Any CPU to avoid 32bit and 64bit mismatch.
- Make sure none of the system services are stuck in starting, if there are any easy thing to do is restart and validate or check your event logs to locate the specific issue

Ours was due to service user, wrong user was mapped which caused the issue.

Regards,
Saj

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an oldie but I was experiencing this issue and couldn't find anything that was helpful so I hope this helps someone else!

The issue had to do with the `sc create "YourServiceNameHere"` command.  When using this command you can supply the parameter `type`, providing the wrong value may be causing the issues.

When running the `sc query "YourServiceNameHere"` command, the result returned that the service was attempting to run using a shared process when it actually needed it's own.

The resolution for me was to change my command from `sc create "YourServiceNameHere" type= share` to `sc create "YourServiceNameHere"`.  After running the service create command with the type specified, change the output of the sc query command and shows it's running in it's own process and the service successfully starts and continues running.

I really hope this helps someone, it caused me much stress!